# How to link directly to paypal payment page?

Tags: html, url, redirect, paypal

H guys. So it is my first time using paypal and I am using it as payment method for my sites membership. Basically in my php I test that the form they submitted is valid and only if it is it redirects you to the paypal link. problem is the link expires of a certain amount of time. I got this link by using their stock pay now button then copying the url, but like I said before that url times out eventually. I am using:

```
if (($desiredusername == "") && ($desiredpassword == "")) { 
    echo ""; 
} elseif (($desiredpassword == $retypepassword) && (mysql_num_rows($results2) != 1) &&
         ($usernamelength <= 15) && ($usernamelength >= 5) && ($passwordlength <= 15) && 
         ($passwordlength >= 5) && ($usernamecontainsspaces == 0) && ($passwordcontainsspaces == 0)) { 
    echo '<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_flow&SESSION=pdbo_yKTkZJZ2i2R9PE7JwUytkmMuDavwDhpNouhJbMSBoUrb4w_ogm95_y&dispatch=50a222a57771920b6a3d7b606239e4d529b525e0b7e69bf0224adecfb0124e9b61f737ba21b081989d37bd8af37ad9708d2162cdad4a70df">'; 
} else {  
    echo ""; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would have begun by reading the integration guide that PayPal provides:

https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_WebsitePaymentsStandard_IntegrationGuide.pdf

Chapter one is actually titled: "Single-Item Payments – Buy Now Buttons"

According to this chapter, you can log in to your account and click "Create PayPal payment button" and it spits out the code for you.

Comment: Indeed, his question is effectively: "I'm copying this URL for a `Buy It Now` button; it works now, but doesn't later. Why?" And my answer is: "Don't do that. That's not how paypal wants you to create a `Buy It Now` button. Read the docs; they tell you to go to their site to generate a button."